# Remote server Laravel installation does not allow my POST request data to pass when POST'ed input value contains the word 'selectors'

Tags: php, laravel

The question title may not be apt - I do not even know what exactly is wrong: I have a Laravel route:
 `Route::post("clients/sync/{command}/{uuid}", "SyncController@handle");`
This route performs well and as expected on my localhost. The posted value is simply a string (of about 10kb size) called `data`. Both `dump($request->input('data'));` and `dump($request->all());` give expected output on my localhost.

However, upon actual deployment, i.e. upload to remote hosting, it seems the input is not passed with the request. `dump($request->input('data'));` simply gives `[]`.

I do not know what to do. I have tried disabling VerifyCsrfToken Middleware, I have tried changing the content-type header to different types, and even disabled all Middlewares altogether, etc... It just won't do the `data` input.

Both local and hosting server running same PHP versions (7.2), and both on Apache.

Kindly help

**UPDATE**
Setting `content-type:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` gives that error I am getting (i.e. no input value passed) on both localhost and remote server. Setting `content-type:"multipart/form-data;` works as expected on localhost, but gives `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` on remote server. Setting `Route::any("clients...` on remote server now gives this same empty error above.

**UPDATE 2**
Based on popular demand, please find below `@handle` controller handler (although I don't think the problem can be from here):

```
public function handle(Request $r, $command, $uuid)
{
    dd($r->all());//I also tried dd($$r->input('data'));

    //but acutally, it does a bunch of stuffs
    //it's just an API endpoint that fecthes a couple of data for the client based on the `data` input variable
    //nothing that I think should cause Symphony's `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` here though
    $c = \App\Client::where('uuid', $uuid)->firstOrFail();
    ...
    return response('ok');
}
```

Postman, localhost:
[image]

Postman, remote hosting server: same settings, same values, etc...
[image]

**UPDATE 3**
When I reduced the length of the string content posted in `data`, the remote server Laravel installation handles it as expected!

**UPDATE 4**
phpinfo() for remote server:
[image]

**UPDATE 5**
I think I may have found a bug. Perhaps the error causing me this sleeplessness is in my web host. Details: when the content of `data` does not contain the word *selectors*, everything is fine. However, when it does, no input is processed (i.e. the "empty" error described above. I will simply keep referring to it as "empty error" hereon)
It does seems it is something that has to do with input handling. It seems input gets filtered in some way because I have now confirmed that it is not in *size* of input but in the *content* of the input. I tested with this: `data = { "attendances": "{\"type\" : \"join\" , \"selectors\" :\"none\"}" }` gives empty error. When I replace `selectors` with a random word like `center`, everything works well, even with very large dataset. It looks like a regex filtering because the same empty error result happens when I replaced with the words `select` and `selection`.

As a workaround, I am now temporarily using the word `celection` for all instances of `selecors` in my large `data` input variable

BTW, the web host is namecheap.com

**UPDATE 5**
Changed title to reflect the issue appropriately.

***Reminder***: localhost works fine, only that remote throws `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException`, but returns empty input for `content-type:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

Comment: What error are you getting on the production server? Turn debug on in your environment file and post the errors. Also check laravel.log and Kindly post your @handle controller method.

Comment: @Polaris `@handle` controller method simply `dump($request->input('data'));` I have updated question with more details

Comment: What's your blade form look like? Please post.

Comment: It's not blade form. I am using Postman for this test. It's for my android app that does API requests.

Comment: Please upload `handle` method

Comment: What's the body of your Postman request look like? And also post the handle() method.

Comment: @Polaris please find details in the now updated edit. `data` in body is simply a bunch of string (sometimes about 10kb in size)

Comment: @DamilolaOlowookere I posted an answer I think may solve the issue.

Comment: @Polaris I think I should change the title of the question from *Laravel does not allow request data to pass on remote server* to *Remote server Laravel installation does not allow my POST request data to pass when POST'ed input value is large* since I have now confirmed that everything works on my remote server when size of posted `data` input variable is small

Comment: @DamilolaOlowookere Something else is definitely wrong. 10kb of data should not be too large for a POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After confirming that it is the webhost (namecheap.com) server issue, I chatted-up their support. I thus got to know that they have a mod_security setting that flagged the request parameters.

Can someone tell me if there is any other host that flags `http://you-domain.com/api/clients/sync/localData/40uanufU8htzGLga?data="{ "attendances": "{\"type\" : \"join\" , \"selectors\" :\"none\"}" }"` as malicious simply because it has the word 'selectors' in this context? Worse still, without any single log anywhere to indicate such to the domain owners?

Comments and reactions please.

(at least such does not occur on my other godaddy account though. @Polaris in his answer below also suggested digitalocean hosting for Laravel hosting)

Answer (score 0):

For the remote server, change your route in web.php to this:

```
Route::post("/api/clients/sync/{command}/{uuid}", "SyncController@handle");
```

And in /app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php make sure the following code is there

```
protected $except = [
    '/api/clients/sync/{command}/{uuid}'
];
```

Set 'content-type' in Postman to:

```
application/json
```

Give this a try and report back any success or errors.

Comment: it is still the same. Please check my updated question (update 3). It seems to be something related to the length of the posted string in the `data` input variable

Comment: Can you post up the output of your phpinfo() ? I'm thinking now it may have to do with your PHP's max post size or max post array length settings.

Comment: You know phpinfo() is a pretty gigantic roll-out! However, I have updated question with relevant section of phpinfo()

Comment: @DamilolaOlowookere How many variables/how many arrays is that data payload you are sending through Postman? Also, can you post the complete error you are getting? I'd like to see the trace and where it's going wrong.

Comment: @DamilolaOlowookere In Postman, try setting the URL to https, removing all headers, and using form-data as the body. I've been reading that many people fix the error by using https with Postman. Also, it can be caused by sending a request body that is too large, in which case you should prune it. Try the above first though and report back.

Comment: please see update 5 at question edit. It seems to be something more than Laravel/PHP. I think that web host is a crap!

Comment: @DamilolaOlowookere I just read update 5. That is very strange. Can you look at your web server logs?

Comment: I don't even know what's going on here man. Server error log is empty (perhaps because the server is on a sub-domain, shared hosting). I guess that's the price I have to pay for crappy namecheap's cheap hosting sh\*t. Sad! Maybe I should report to their support so they can fix their a\*\*? I guess I'll just post them this SO link for all I care. I hope they'll be humble enough to acknowledge this shitty error . What'd you think?

Comment: @DamilolaOlowookere Hmm... try DigitialOcean.com and Laravel Forge to deploy your app. I highly recommend.